# Java, generate selected list of enum values

Tags: java, enums

I have a project where I use enum class with 128 values in it and I want to allow end user to select only few of values for his usage (say 20 out of 128) For that I created javafx tableview with checkbotablecell which works nicely but then I would need to make boolean field in enum to define visibility of each value but all enum fields are final and I will not be able to change it dynamically. So, the question is how to dynamically define visibility of each enum value?

Comment: Put the values you want to be "visible" in an EnumSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Map of Enum to Boolean inside Enum class.

Eg : `static final EnumMap<EnumType , Boolean> visibilityMap`.

And add getter and setter methods to access visibility.

Comment: EnumMap<EnumType, Boolean> to be precise. Now need to populate tableview with it.

Answer (score 1):

You want an [**EnumSet**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) to be stored.

The enum class of yours defines 128 singleton objects, one cannot have several objects *"being"* the same enum object. The solution would be to have a class *containing* the enum object. Or having an EnumSet of several enum constants.

EnumSet is a Set implementation havily optimized for enums, and providing building methods.
In the constructor on passes the actual enum class itself so with type erasure the class can still function.

```
EnumSet<Weekday> weekend = EnumSet.of(Weekday.SATURDAY, Weekday.SUNDAY);
```